# How to add textbox on plot in plotly R?

Tags: r, textbox, plotly

I would like to add a text-box or information text on plot generated with plotly.
It seems like that now.
[without text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgPgk.jpg)

I want to make it with text-box as follows (no need to circle:))).

[with text-box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1BzZ.png)

The code so far:

```
p <- plot_ly(data=data.mosann, x = ~Combined, y = ~Actual)%>%
  layout(shapes=list(type='line', x0= 0, x1= 235, y0=0, y1=235, line=list(color='red',width=3)),
         title = 'Scatter Plot Measurements-Combined Improvements MinT',
         xaxis = list(title = "Combined MinT", showgrid = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Measurements", showgrid = TRUE))
p
```

Comment: Not sure it will work but have you try using `ggplot` and convert to `plotly` using `ggplotly`? In `ggplot` you can add text using the `annotate` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Change the `x` and `y` for layout annotation based on where you want your text.

```
p <- plot_ly(data=data.mosann, x = ~Combined, y = ~Actual)%>%
  layout(xaxis = ~Combined, yaxis = ~Actual, 
         annotations = list(text = "YOUR TEXT HERE",  x = 200, y = 30,showarrow=FALSE ),
         shapes=list(type='line', x0= 0, x1= 235, y0=0, y1=235, line=list(color='red',width=3)),
         title = 'Scatter Plot Measurements-Combined Improvements MinT',
         xaxis = list(title = "Combined MinT", showgrid = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Measurements", showgrid = TRUE))
```

Comment: It gives a weird error, "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". I checked there is no $ sign in the code.

Comment: change `xaxis` and `yaxis` in layout to some appropriate numbers. ex: `xaxis = 30, yaxis = 200`, or try `xaxis = x, yaxis = y`

Comment: Its taking ~ sign as error, no worries `xaxis = x, yaxis = y` should work, also you will have to combine `xaxis = list(title = "Combined MinT", showgrid = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Measurements", showgrid = TRUE)) ` togeather with it.